# Can I give any code block for __getitem__() and __setitem__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the python [operator documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html), the `__getitem__(a, b)` is said to:

> Return the value of *a* at index *b*.

I know using `__getitem__(x, i)` makes `x[i]` being equivalent to `type(x).__getitem__(x, i)`.

In below example, when I try to print strings like `"Taco Bell"` in `__getitem__(self, items)` function it still works.

```
class Test(object):
    # This function prints the type
    # of the object passed as well
    # as the object item
    def __getitem__(self, items):
        print ("Taco Bell")

# Driver code
test = Test()
test[5]
test[5:65:5]
test['GeeksforGeeks']
test[1, 'x', 10.0]
test['a':'z':2]
test[object()]
```

Prints:

```
Taco Bell
Taco Bell
Taco Bell
Taco Bell
Taco Bell
Taco Bell
```

What does it mean? Is it that I can give any code block for `__getitem__()` in python?

Comment: Yes, it can do anything. The operator docs are wrong, and seem to refer only the common usage of list or tuple indexing.

Comment: @wim a lot of stuff in Python works this way, the data-model docs specify the way something *should* behave, but that isn't enforced by the runtime. There are exceptions, e.g. `__str__`,`__bool__`, `__int__` etc will error if you don't return a `str`,`bool`, or `int` object respectively, but that's because `str`, `bool`, and `int` are *constructors* for those types, it would be weird if they returned something that wasn't those types

Comment: You're looking at the wrong documentation (admittedly, misleading documentation). `__getitem__`'s prototype comes from [the data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getitem__#object.__getitem__). The `operator` module is just a set of functions that wrap built-in operators, but it doesn't define the rules for how you'd overload them. The data model is clear that it's for any use of `self[key]`, where the values `key` can take depend on what you accept (for mappings, it could be anything). The methods can do anything, it's up to you to use them wisely.

Comment: Note that you are not actually returning "Taco Bell" from `__getitem__` here. You just print it, and return `None`.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the arguments, and as @wim notes, you aren't returning any values.

Depending on your implementation, you could make it behave like a mapping, or even a list. (For the latter, you'll get a slice instance, to let you do stuff like test[3:6])

Comment: Note that the `operator` module isn't canonical, since it's only documenting the free functions it provides. The canonical place documenting the special member function is https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method:

```
def __getitem__(self, items):
    print ("Taco Bell")
```

Implicitly returns `None`, like any other Python function/method which does not have an explicit `return` statement. So you *are* returning something.

```
>>> t = Test()
>>> t[0] is None
Taco Bell
True
>>> t['foo'] is None
Taco Bell
True
```

In any case, yes, the code in the `__getitem__` method (or really any other method) can be arbitrary, you can do whatever you want. Of course, you are expected to do something with the argument that you are given (e.g. use it to look it up an item somehow), but you can also very well ignore it. Whether or not this makes sense is up to you.